# How can I generate html script tags for webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to setup webpack-dev-server with a backend (my express server) and the issue I'm having is, from the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server):

```
generate HTML pages with <script src="http://localhost:8080/assets/bundle.js">.
```

I can do this by hand, but the issue is that I'd have to edit them before production, etc.

Please tell me there's something I'm missing, and webpack can handle this task. I am setting up the 'iframe' method.

Answer (score 0):

[html-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) can generate the `script` tags for you.